# How to release data tables from the memory after like say 5 min automatically

Tags: java, database, caching

I have a TableHandler which implements table loading / reloading logic. By table I mean the data I load from either disc or memory when a user request for it in the form of table object. If a new request arrives and the instance of table is in memory then I just loads the table from memory and don't reloads it from disc. If the table I am looking for is not present in memory I just loads the table from disc. Now As my request are increasing a lot of tables are getting stored in memory so I want to release some tables automatically from memory after say 5 min which aren't been excessed for a duration of 5 min. How can I implement it?
I have tablehandler class structure like this

```
final class TableHandler{

   /*
   Data struct for storing information required for management 
   of the loaded table    instances
   */

    final static class Tableinfo{

       /*
       Table instance.. and other things like table when 
       last modified and whether to referench the table 
       when a next request arrives.
       */

    }

    getTable(){someInternalTableHandler.getTable()}

    replacetable {someInternalTableHandler.replacetable()}

    //Handles loading/reloading logic.

    final static class someInternalTablehandler{

        getTable(){...}
        createTableInstance(){...}
        replaceTable{...}

    } 
}
```

How can I implement the above said logic into my code....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Guava MapMaker to do this:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

```
Map map = new MapMaker().expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).makeMap();
```

If you don't want to hard code it to a time, you can use soft references for your values in the created map.  This will cause your map's values to be dropped if they are no longer referenced and the JVM is running out of memory.

Rolling your own map that uses weak/soft references to clear itself isn't too hard either.  Take a look at [ReferenceQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html), [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), and [SoftReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)

There are some projects that allow you to annotate a method with `@Cache` and all return values of that method will be cached and cleared when no longer referenced. http://code.google.com/p/tantalizing-eats/

Answer (score 2):

That sounds exactly like a Cache of tables in memory. Take a look at java caching solutions like EHCache, which solves this problem and many more.

If you want to do it yourself, add a timestamp to your Tableinfo class to store the last access time. Then use a timer task as jzd suggest to traverse a the list of TableInfo looking for those that must be "unloaded".

Check [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54) for an example of using Timer and TimerTask

Comment: I already have a timestamp field like last modified in the tableinfo ...but how do i implement the timer task...??code would be great...

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. If your goal is to refresh the data so that duplicate requests eventually see new data.  Then just add a Date to your Tableinfo class of when the data was pulled last.  Then only use the copy from memory if the date is in the last five minutes.
2. If your goal is to reduce memory usage and you have a lot of tables, then create a new Timer that after 5 minutes executes a TimerTask that removes the table from memory.

Comment: I already have a timestamp field like last modified in the tableinfo ...but how do i implement the timer task...??code would be great...

Comment: Extend TimerTask with an implementation that clears your table data.  Use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html to schedule the task.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the `java.lang.ref.WeakReference` and `java.lang.ref.SoftReference` classes might be what you're looking for.

Having only a weak reference behaves as if you released all references to an object, allowing it to be cleaned up by the GC whenever it wants.  If the GC hasn't cleaned up your table you can still use it, if it has cleaned it up you would need to reload it.  A soft reference is similar, but the object will generally be kept around longer and finalized only if you're running low on memory.

If you want any guarantees like that things are cleared after 5 minutes of inactivity, you'll have to use a third-party library or do something yourself, none of the built-in classes will provide that.